# Mongodb C# driver throwing Element Name '_t' is not valid on UpdateOneAsync

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am getting MongoDb.Bson.SerializationException: 'Element name '_t' is not valid.
I read all posts online that appear to be similar issue at first, however, in those posts, element name is specified, here, i am only getting '_t' even by trying different class objects.

```
        var database = AppConfig.client.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("testcollection");

        var filter = Builders<Student>.Filter.Eq(g => g.Name, "oldName");
        

        var update = Builders<Student>.Update.Set(g => g.Name, "NewName");

        var updateResult = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter.ToBsonDocument(), update.ToBsonDocument());
```

Also, for all examples i have seen online for UpdateOneAsync function, filter and update below do NOT need to be BSON documents, however, my code won't compile unless I do .ToBSONDocument() as above.

**var updateResult = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);**

My class is minimal:

```
    public class Student
    {
      [BsonElement("Name")]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      [BsonElement("Age")]
      public int Age { get; set; }
    
     }
```

Can someone please help figure out what is wrong with above?

**Update: How to use render for Update.Set**

```
        var registry = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry;
        var serializer = registry.GetSerializer<Student>();

        var filter = Builders<Student>.Filter.Eq(g=> g.Name, "NewName").Render(serializer, registry);
```

//I think update syntax is not correct.

```
        var update = Builders<Student>.Update.Set(g => g.Name, "Changed").Render(serializer, registry);


//update is throwing error:cannot convert from Mongodb.bson.bsonvalue to mongodb.Driver.updatedefinition<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument
            var updateResult = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

Comment: please provide actual values (for both filter and update) after calling `ToBsonDocument`

Comment: Name is a string. and "oldName" and "NewName" are actual values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's impossible to use `ToBsonDocument` as you did. The easiest fix is using not typed builders:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("name", "oldName");
```

If you want to use typed builder, you should call `Render` as below:

```
        var registry = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry;
        var serializer = registry.GetSerializer<Student>();
        var filter = Builders<Student>.Filter.Eq(e=>e.Name, "oldName").Render(serializer, registry);
```

Comment: can u please write complete code including filters and UpdateOneAsync. Is using typed filters optional?

Comment: Just replace `Builders<Student>` on `Builders<BsonDocument>` and `g => g.Name` on `"name"` and do not use `ToBsonDocument()`. 
`Is using typed filters optional` => both ways work. But in your case, the collection type is `BsonDocument`, that's why the expected argument for `UpdateOneAsync` is also `BsonDocument`. You cannot call `ToBsonDocument`, because if you check the result in this case (as I suggested), then you can see that the result has nothing common to your data at all, this is expected behavior. To get `BsonDocument` from a filter, you should use `Render` method.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. Can you please see updated post, How do i use render for update.Set. if you can update your answer to include update (as you did with filter), it will solve my issue

Comment: use: `collection.UpdateOne(filter, update.AsBsonDocument);`

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my problem :)